remap '-' key in BASH vi normal mode to "cd .."
I just discovered vi mode in bash that I enable with
set -o vi
in my .bashrc.
Now I was quite excited to remap the "normal mode" equivalents to some handy functionality. First and foremost I wanted to remap the dash-key to change directory one up from the current. I tried this:
# Remap "-" key to "cd .." in vi normal mode
bind -m vi-command '"-": "cd ..\n"'

but it doesn't seem to be working. Where did I go wrong and how to accomplish that?

Hm, "some handy functionality" is matter of opinion. For me - functionality (go to previous directory) is much more helpful than go to upper directory.

@RomeoNinov regardless, how would you set it? - is normally mapped to "previous history" (https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline)[from here]

Have you try with alias?

"it doesn't seem to be working" - what did you try to test it, and what did happen (or didn't happen)?

I would have thought that from your description -(){ cd ..; } would be what you wanted

@ChrisDavies No that's just a function alias and i still have to type. I want to capture keystrokes with readline and directly invoke filesystem operations.

If you want to run a command, without inserting text onto the line, you can do, eg. :
bind -m vi-command -x '"-": "cd .."'

That will leave any text that you might have already edited on the CLI unchanged.
Note, however, that this will not automatically re-evaluate/re-draw your prompt/$PS1. So, if that contains something like \w to show the working directory, that won't (yet) be updated (until the next command).
If you'd rather have the prompt immediately updated (to reflect the new working directory), you can do:
bind -m vi-command -x '"-": "cd ..; kill -INT $$ "'

But, that has the disadvantage that any text you were editing on the CLI will also be cleared. I'm not aware of any way to achieve both of those features at once.

You're mapping something in normal mode. To insert text in the command line, you need to go back to insert mode (e.g., using i), so:
bind -m vi-command '"-": "icd ..\n"'


Oh that seems to work, but is it possible to make it work on a non-clear readline? e.g. if stuff is already there the cd ..\n would just pollute the line and the command is not found.  It should first replace the whole line with cd ..\n and then resubstitute the original line content. Is this possible?

@glades use 0C instead of i - 0 to go to start of line and C to replace all text.

Ok then I could also just use S. But how to paste? I need to somehow exit insert mode again right?  doesn't work (like it would in vim)

Use \e instead of <esc>.

Ok I made it work thx! Which makes me wonder if there's a possibility to directly invoke cd without taking the route via the string output?

I don't think there's a readline command to directly execute something

I figured out that you can use bind -m vi-command -x '"-":"cd .."' which seems to work well. But now the problem is that the line is still stuck at the old dir, so I would need to redraw the line (preferably with builtin command redraw-current-line, but it seems bindand bind -x are not combine-able. Any ideas?

Well, you already have something that works, so just continue using that?

It works but I can't see that it did since the prompt is not updated that's a problem..

@glades that's not a problem you have with the cd ..\n solution, now, is it? It's one you created for yourself by using the -x version instead.
